# after element of a particular row giving extra unwanted space in footer in materialize . want to remove it

Tags: html, css, materialize, footer

I created a row in footer and it's giving me extra unwanted space of same color as footer , in inspect it's showing of after element automatically created after creation of row.

When i try to remove it by margin top:-12rem; it gets removed but all the row's are disturbed . But it gives no  response to specific id or class.

```css
.page-footer {
  /* position: relative; */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black!important;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 640px;
}

#frow {
  min-width: 640px;
  margin-top: -15rem!important;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-footer ">
  <div class=" row " style="margin-top: -13rem;" id="frow">
    <div class="col l4 s12 m4">
      <h5>About CLub</h5>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col l4 s12 m4">
      <h5>Memberships</h5>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Join</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Renew</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Benifits</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> IEEE Collaboration</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col l4 s12 m4">

      <h5>Grow With Us</h5>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">get involved</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="color: white;text-align: center; ">
    <p>We'll your encourage ideas and shape your future </p>
  </div>
  <div style="color: white;text-align: center; ">
    <a href="www.facebook.com" class="social-icon"><i class="fab fa-facebook">&nbsp;</i></a>
    <a href="www.instagram.com" class="social-icon"><i class="fab fa-instagram">&nbsp;</i></a>
    <a href="www.twitter.com" class="social-icon"><i class="fab fa-twitter">&nbsp;</i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please can you include HTML for the footer element in your code block _ And any custom CSS would also be useful

Comment: Needfull is done with full code of the footer

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the div and try to use section as your tag .So that the class will be enclosed in section tag in.It might be useful instead of div or better still use paragraph tag it will be a lot more useful for you.

Comment: Thanx for the advice , but it  did no effect the space is still there